# Canon Edsdk 3.09 reset image counter/number

Tags: c#, edsdk, camera-api

Is there a way in Canon's Edsdk to reset the file numbering to 1?

I take images in shutter mode and have to reset after a given time.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. I've used the SDK extensively and checked the documentation again but couldn't find anything. If you just want to change the name  when downloading, you can do that, but not the files on the camera memory.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this belongs here but try this: 
https://support.usa.canon.com/kb/index?page=content&id=ART167999&cat=DSLR&actp=LIST

Comment: sorry, this doesn't help. My question is for an API function